# How to define a Laravel factory without a model?

Tags: laravel, testing

I'm controller testing and essentially want to define a `factory` to represent a post from the internet.

This post gets split up into several models in the controller.

I'm functional testing the whole controller though so how do I create a `factory` without a model to represent a front end post?

It appears `factory` are made like this:

```
$factory->define(App\Models\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

static $password;

return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```

Its the `App\Models\User::class` that's throwing me. I want a generic one that's not tied to the `User` model or any model.

Comment: So like in the context of that function I could simply make up anything to replace App\Models\User::class?  

And that would be how I call that factory?

Comment: Factories probably depend on the model now that I think about it because of the make and create commands.  However, model factories are not the only way to generate fake data.  Write your own function that uses faker to generate an object..

Comment: try  `$modelMock = Mockery::mock('App\Model');` and on your model factory call that class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to generate create a Query Builder instance in the seeder.  So, for example, you want sample data in the balloons table :

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert(
  [
   'name' => $faker->name, 
   'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail, 
   'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
   'remember_token' => str_random(10)
 ]
);
```

And you would have to do this for every row you want to insert into your given table. 
You wouldn't worry about the model factory since there isn't a model.

Comment: Hi, do you maybe know how to run this multiple times (for example 5 times) just by doing one command **```php artisan migrate:refresh --seed``** ? Not by coping and pasting your answer multiple times in **DatabaseSeeder**

Answer (score 3):

you can use Faker that already comes with laravel

```
use Faker\Factory;

$faker = Factory::create();
```

then use the faker as you use it in factories with models in laravel

i did that in seeder class

[here what i did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58rxq.png)